# ESP32-WROOM-32D and LiDar sensor data processing issue. (Probably array issue?)

Tags: arduino-esp32, lidar

I'm trying to using LIDAR sensor for my project, but there is problem.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define PACKET_ALL (5 + 323 + 1) // HEADER3 + LENGTH2 + PAYLOAD + CHECKSUM

SoftwareSerial CygLiDAR(8, 9);

byte packetbuffer[PACKET_ALL] = {0};
byte checksum = 0;
volatile bool finish_buf = false;

int buffCnt = 0;
int state = 0;
int CLcount = 0;
unsigned int distanceA[161] = {0};
unsigned int distanceB[161] = {0};
unsigned int *distance;

byte Start_LiDAR[8] = {0x5A, 0x77, 0xFF, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03};

void setup() {
  CygLiDAR.begin(57600);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  // Start LiDAR
  CygLiDAR.write(Start_LiDAR, sizeof(Start_LiDAR));
  CygLiDAR.available();
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {
  CygSerialEvent();

  if (finish_buf == true) {
    finish_buf = false;
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 161; i++) {
      Serial.print("Distance ");
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.print(": ");
      Serial.println(distance[i]);
    }
  }
  
}

void CygSerialEvent() {
  while (finish_buf == false) {
    int bufSize;
    bufSize = CygLiDAR.readBytes(packetbuffer, PACKET_ALL);

    for (int i = 0; i < bufSize; i++) {
      if (state == 0) {
        buffCnt = 0;
        if (packetbuffer[i] == 0x5A) {
          state = 1;
        }
      } else if (state == 1) {
        if (packetbuffer[i] == 0x77) {
          state = 2;
        } else {
          state = 0;
        }
      } else if (state == 2) {
        if (packetbuffer[i] == 0xFF) {
          state = 3;
        } else {
          state = 0;
        }
      } else if (state == 3) {
        if (packetbuffer[i] == 0x43) {
          checksum = 0;
          state = 4;
          checksum ^= packetbuffer[i];
        } else {
          state = 0;
        }
      } else if (state == 4) {
        if (packetbuffer[i] == 0x01) {
          state = 5;
          checksum ^= packetbuffer[i];
        } else {
          state = 0;
        }
      } else if (state == 5) {
        if (packetbuffer[i] == 0x01) {
          if (buffCnt % 2 == 0) {
            distanceA[buffCnt / 2] = ((packetbuffer[i] << 8) & 0xFF00);
          } else {
            distanceA[buffCnt / 2] |= (unsigned int)packetbuffer[i];
          }
          state = 6;
          checksum ^= packetbuffer[i];
          CLcount = 0;
        } else {
          state = 0;
        }
      } else if (state == 6) { // scan
        checksum ^= packetbuffer[i];
        
        if (CLcount % 2 == 0) {
          distanceB[CLcount / 2] = ((packetbuffer[i] << 8) & 0xFF00);
        } else {
          distanceB[CLcount / 2] |= (unsigned int)packetbuffer[i];
        }
        
        CLcount++;
        
        if (CLcount >= 322) {
          state = 7;
        }
      } else if (state == 7) { // checksum
        CLcount = 0;
        state = 0;
        
        if (checksum == packetbuffer[i]) {
          finish_buf = true;
        }
        
        checksum = 0;
      } else {
        state = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my First Code to operate the sensor for Arduino UNO, and it works well.
I don't know why since each baud rates are different, anyway it works..

But on plan, I have to use ESP32-WROOM-32D, I modified this code since ESP32 doesn't support softwareserial, and the result is this

````
#define PACKET_ALL (5 + 323 + 1) // HEADER3 + LENGTH2 + PAYLOAD + CHECKSUM

HardwareSerial CygLiDAR(0);

byte packetbuffer[PACKET_ALL] = {0};
byte checksum = 0;
volatile bool finish_buf = false;

int buffCnt = 0;
int state = 0;
int CLcount = 0;
unsigned int distanceA[161] = {0};
unsigned int distanceB[161] = {0};
unsigned int *distance;

byte Start_LiDAR[8] = {0x5A, 0x77, 0xFF, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03};

void setup() {
  CygLiDAR.begin(57600); 
  Serial.begin(57600);   

  // Start LiDAR
  CygLiDAR.write(Start_LiDAR, sizeof(Start_LiDAR));
  CygLiDAR.available();
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {
   while (!finish_buf) {
    CygSerialEvent();
  }
  if (finish_buf == true) {
    finish_buf = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 161; i++) {
      Serial.print("Distance ");
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.print(": ");
      Serial.println(distance[i]);
    }
  }
}

void CygSerialEvent() {
  while (finish_buf == false) {
    int bufSize;
    bufSize = CygLiDAR.readBytes(packetbuffer, PACKET_ALL);

    for (int i = 0; i < bufSize; i++) {
      if (state == 0) {
        buffCnt = 0;
        if (packetbuffer[i] == 0x5A) {
          state = 1;

        }
      } else if (state == 1) {
        if (packetbuffer[i] == 0x77) {
          state = 2;
        } else {
          state = 0;
        }
      } else if (state == 2) {
        if (packetbuffer[i] == 0xFF) {
          state = 3;
        } else {
          state = 0;
        }
      } else if (state == 3) {
        if (packetbuffer[i] == 0x43) {
          checksum = 0;
          state = 4;
          checksum ^= packetbuffer[i];
        } else {
          state = 0;
        }
      } else if (state == 4) {
        if (packetbuffer[i] == 0x01) {
          state = 5;
          checksum ^= packetbuffer[i];
        } else {
          state = 0;
        }
      } else if (state == 5) {
        if (packetbuffer[i] == 0x01) {
          if (buffCnt % 2 == 0) {
            distanceA[buffCnt / 2] = ((packetbuffer[i] << 8) & 0xFF00);
          } else {
            distanceA[buffCnt / 2] |= (unsigned int)packetbuffer[i];
          }
          state = 6;
          checksum ^= packetbuffer[i];
          CLcount = 0;
        } else {
          state = 0;
        }
      } else if (state == 6) { // scan
        checksum ^= packetbuffer[i];

        if (CLcount % 2 == 0) {
          distanceB[CLcount / 2] = ((packetbuffer[i] << 8) & 0xFF00);
        } else {
          distanceB[CLcount / 2] |= (unsigned int)packetbuffer[i];
        }

        CLcount++;

        if (CLcount >= 322) {
          state = 7;
        }
      } else if (state == 7) { // checksum
        CLcount = 0;
        state = 0;

        if (checksum == packetbuffer[i]) {
          finish_buf = true;
        }

        checksum = 0;
      } else {
        state = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}```

And when I uploaded this on ESP32, it's yelling like :
````

Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x400d15ab  PS      : 0x00060830  A0      : 0x800d1f04  A1      : 0x3ffc5840
A2      : 0x00000000  A3      : 0x3ffc2314  A4      : 0x3ffc1bc0  A5      : 0x00004e20
A6      : 0x00000070  A7      : 0x80000001  A8      : 0x00000000  A9      : 0x3ffc5820
A10     : 0x0000000f  A11     : 0x0000000d  A12     : 0x0000000a  A13     : 0x00000001
A14     : 0x00000149  A15     : 0x00000000  SAR     : 0x00000018  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x400862d9  LEND    : 0x400862e9  LCOUNT  : 0xffffffff

Backtrace: 0x400d15a8:0x3ffc5840 0x400d1f01:0x3ffc5860

ELF file SHA256: 7049cb342730e9c3

```
This is the change:
1. Communication with SoftwareSerial to HardwareSerial
2. The baud rate of Lidar and ESP32 are matched

I found that some array issue and occur this problem, so I tried to combine distanceA with distanceB, then ESP32 doesn't go INFINITE REBOOT STATE, but Values from Sensor are "0", except First value (distance[0] = 256 or 65535)

Can anyone help to solve this problem? I'm Korean, so I'm sorry to have bad english, but I hope you guys understand..thx
```

Comment: 1) Correction, it not that esp32 doesn’t “support “ SoftwareSerial, it is that esp32 doesn’t need SoftwareSerial because it has more than one hardware serial interface. 2) to use the hardware serial, you simple use the `Serial1` or `Serial2` directly depend on which one you connected to.